# The milk spilled out

Tags: word-usage

He has finished drinking the milk and refused to give me the bottle.

The milk spilled out from the feeding bottle.

> "See. The milk spilled out."

Does spilled out described well as the image?

[image]

Comment: This US English speaker would usually say just "spilled", not "spilled out".  I would only add *out* if I needed to clarify exactly where it was out of, like "out of the hole in the bucket" or whatever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's fine.

Depending on just how this happened, it MIGHT be more appropriate to say "sprayed out". Usually when we say "spilled", we're thinking of a liquid falling out of a cup or bowl. If the liquid is coming out of a small hole like that we usually say "sprayed" it if came out quickly, maybe "dribbled" if it came out slowly. But "spilled out" is acceptable.

Answer (score 3):

You could also say

> The milk **squirted** from the rubber nipple.